# Airflow hide_paused_dags_by_default on airflow.cfg is not working

Tags: python, etl, airflow

I want to hide all my Paused DAGs on UI but the configuration on airflow.cfg does not seem to work.

```
# By default, the webserver shows paused DAGs. Flip this to hide paused
# DAGs by default
hide_paused_dags_by_default = True #False by default
```

Steps I did so far to make it work:

- Restart airflow webserver , scheduler and worker
- Delete airflow.cfg and do `airflow initdb` (desperate move)

Comment: You just need to change the config in `airflow.cfg` file and restart webserver. you don't need to delete `airflow.cfg` file or do `airflow initdb`

Comment: how are you running airflow? if you're using Docker, you can `docker exec` into the webserver/scheduler container with bash and `printenv` to see if that env is getting set correctly. there should also be a hyperlink on bottom left of the airflow web UI that should toggle showPaused

Comment: @kaxil as you can see on my code snippet, I did changed the airflow.cfg 
hide_paused_dags_by_default = True #False by default. I also mention that I did restart my webserver as well. I only deleted my airflow.cfg and initb db because the first solution does not work.

Comment: @rob  I am running my airflow with systemd, are there any workaround for that ?

Comment: Still looking for this answer

Comment: Does anyone has the same issue ? Still looking for an answer. I might miss something

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `systemd`, check whether all Airflow processes are killed

```
systemctl status airflow-webserver
systemctl status airflow-scheduler
systemctl status airflow-worker

# Stop them if they are "active" 
systemctl stop airflow-webserver
systemctl stop airflow-scheduler
systemctl stop airflow-worker
```

also verify it using `ps aux | grep airflow`

Then change you `airflow.cfg` file and re-run the all the airflow services

```
systemctl restart airflow-webserver
systemctl restart airflow-scheduler
systemctl restart airflow-worker
```

Comment: I tried this @kaxil, unfortunately still did't work. I tried to change other configuration  on airflow.cfg such as load_example = True and it works after I restarted the airflow webserver. However it is not working on hide_paused_dags_by_default 

I wonder if this is a bug on airflow's end.

Answer (score 0):

For those using Google Cloud Composer, you can achieve this by adding the following entry to `Airflow Configuration Overrides`:

```
Section: webserver
    Key: hide_paused_dags_by_default
  Value: true
```